# can anybody help me in this code

Tags: jquery

For some reason when i click book list element it shows both forms(books and classes) instead of just book form as if there is no break statement,i am really confused why is it doing that?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
$('.hideshares').hide();
 $('#shareupdate li').click(function(){
 switch($(this).attr('id')){
case "book":
$('.hideshares').hide();
$('#bk').show();

break;

case "class":
$('.hideshares').hide();
$('#cs').show();
break;
}
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul id="shareupdate" >
<li id="book" >Books</li>   
<li id="class">classes</li>
</ul>
</div>

 <div id="sharecontainer">               
<form id="bk" class="hideshares">
<div id="bookneeds"><input type="radio" id="ndbook" value="needbk" name="books" />Need book
<input type="radio" id="pstbook" value="postbk" name="books" />Post book 
</div>
</form>

<form id="cs" class="hideshares">
<div><label>class:</label> <input type="text" id="cls" size="10"/></div>
<div> <input type="radio" id="dntknw" name="dontknw"/>I don't know yet </div>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've been here a little while. Take more care when composing your questions. Read them after you post. We tire of cleaning them up.

Answer (score 0):

Made acouple of changes in appearance and function calling but your post pretty much worked for me without many problems; check out my Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sadmicrowave/FeBW9/